# How to specify a condition inside a for_loop

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+

How do i use a condition inside a for_each such that , the below resource is created/triggered only when validation_method == "DNS" else ignores the creation of a resource. However in earlier terraform (11 versions) we can use

> count =  var.validation_method == "DNS" ? length(var.domain_names) : 0

My var.domain_names is map(list(string)) , eg

```
domain_names = {
    "foo.com" = ["*.foo.com"]
  }
```

Please suggest me some solutions. Using terraform 0.12.20 version

```
resource "aws_route53_record" "validation" {
  for_each   = var.validation_method == "DNS" ? var.domain_names :
  name       = aws_acm_certificate.certificate[each.key].domain_validation_options.0.resource_record_name
  type       = aws_acm_certificate.certificate[each.key].domain_validation_options.0.resource_record_type
  zone_id    = data.aws_route53_zone.selected[each.key].zone_id
  ttl        = "300"
  records    = [aws_acm_certificate.certificate.domain_validation_options.0.resource_record_value]
  depends_on = [aws_acm_certificate.certificate.domain_name]
}
```

Comment: The false on the ternary would likely be an empty list `[]`, but it seems like your true conditional would fail at the moment, so we need more information to fully answer.

Comment: yes, i didn't know how i should set the condition inside a for_each , true and false should have consistent types, Any other solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you noted, you need to have consistent types on both sides of the ternary. Since you are using a `map(list(string))` the right side, in order to create no resources, would need to be an empty map: `{}`.

```
variable "domain_names" {
  type = map(list(string))
  default = {
    "foo.com" = ["*.foo.com"]
  }
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "validation" {
  for_each   = var.validation_method == "DNS" ? var.domain_names : {}
  ...
}
```